# CSS transition not working in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, css-transitions

CSS3 transition works fine in an HTML page, but not in a .aspx page.  Is there a way to overcome this?  I'd like to do the app in Web Forms as it makes designing the forms much easier.  Any input would be appreciated.

Here is the .aspx page:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="CMSWebForms.Index" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />  
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <link href="Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/test.css"/>


</head>
<body>
    <ul id="sidebar" class="dropdown-menu text-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display: block;  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;">
        <li><h1 class="text-center"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CMS</a></h1></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-right">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#" id="myId">Sales</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu text-right">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Customers</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-right">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" id="myId">Pricing</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">A</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">B</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">C</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">D</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">E</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Quotes</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Orders</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Reports</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <!--<p>&nbsp;</p>-->
        <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-right">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#" id="myId">Manufacturing</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Three</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Four</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!--</div>-->
    <!--<div id="wrapper">-->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li>
                        <button id="sidebarToggle" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                         <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Log in
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="content-header container-fluid text-center">
            <h1 id="home" class="">
                CMS
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="page-content inset container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    <h1 class="">Hello Beautiful!</h1>
                    <p class="">

                    </p>
                    Name:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="248px"></asp:TextBox>
                    Address:
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="248px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"  class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
                <h4 class="text-center text-primary">&copy;2016 Apiron Technologies, Inc.</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#sidebar{
  background: #000;
  color: #999999;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 0;  
  transition: .25s;
}

#sidebar.dropdown-menu.text-right.hide-sidebar{
    left: -200px !important;
    transition: .25s;
}

.navbar.navbar-inverse{
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    background: #1536b6 !important;
}

.navbar-inverse
.navbar-inverse .nav>li>a {
    color: #fff !important;
}

.btn-info{
    color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-bottom{
   margin-left: 200px !important;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 200px;
    transition: .25s;  
}

#page-content-wrapper.hide-sidebar{
    margin-left: 0;
    transition: .25s;
}

.dropdown-menu {
 border-radius: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  background: #000;
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;

}

.dropdown-menu li a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-menu.text-right li a {
  background: #000;
  color: #999999;

  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;

}

.dropdown-menu.text-right li a:hover,
.dropdown-menu.text-right li.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333131 ;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-right{
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#myId  {
    color: aqua;

}
```

and here is the JS:

```
 (function () {

    var $sidebarAndWrapper = $("#sidebar,#page-content-wrapper");
    var $icon = $("#sidebarToggle i.fa");

    $("#sidebarToggle").on("click", function () {
        $sidebarAndWrapper.toggleClass("hide-sidebar");
        if ($sidebarAndWrapper.hasClass("hide-sidebar")) {
            $icon.removeClass("fa-angle-left");
            $icon.addClass("fa-angle-right");
        }
        else {
            $icon.removeClass("fa-angle-right");
            $icon.addClass("fa-angle-left");
        }
    });


})();
```

Comment: Try loading your css files first & then js files. Not sure this will work or not but at some places they refer to load css first & then to load js

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" /> ` and what's this ? Is this how you load js file? It's wrong

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you checking in? Try using another browser.
Once i had a same problem. Resetting IIS site fixed the issue. You can also try prefixing CSS.

Cheers

Comment: Prefixing CSS how?

Comment: Vendor prefixing. Use this one https://autoprefixer.github.io/ just paste your css and it will prefix for you.

Have you tried resetting IIS site ?

Comment: I'm using Chrome.  Chrome works in HTML.  I think the problem is that toggleClass isn't working; it toggles for a second but then the original page returns.  I think I need to prevent postback when the button is clicked.